# Nginx ошибка 502 при попытке запуска проекта Django (gunicorn + nginx)

Tags: linux, django, nginx, uwsgi, gunicorn

Делал подключение по инструкции с этого сайта: https://www.8host.com/blog/razrabotka-django-prilozheniya-na-postgresql-nginx-gunicorn-v-debian-8/

Сайт запускается с помощью `gunicorn` или `manage.py runserver`, но с помощью nginx по адресу myip:80, появляется ошибка "502 Bad Gateway"

Результат команды "systemctl status gunicorn" в целом как в инструкции и статус тоже Active, только в самом низу есть строка: `systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed to set invocation ID on control group /system.slice/gunicorn`.

Файл webserver.sock (myproject.sock в инструкции) в каталоге с проектом есть и он принадлежит группе www-data.

Результат команды `nginx -t` такой же, как и в инструкции, ошибок нет.
Командой `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 webserver.wsgi:application` сервер работает корректно.

В чём может быть проблема, пожалуйста подскажите.

Прикладываю содержимое файлов `/etc/nginx/sites-available/webserver` (в инструкции ../myproject) и `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А также посмотрел логи /var/log/nginx/error.log и кажется вот причина этой ошибки, но я не знаю как её исправить:

```
2018/08/10 01:49:42 [crit] 6725#6725: *10 connect() to unix:/root/webserver/webserver.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 62.33.42.33.49.20, server: 46.36.219.171, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/root/webserver/webserver.sock:/", host: "46.36.219.171"
```

Права у `webserver.sock - srwxrwxrwx 1 root www-data`

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить рекомендации отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872174/wsgi-nginx-error-permission-denied-while-connecting-to-upstream

Comment: @floydya, спасибо, снова выручаете) Эта ошибка пропала после того, как я изменил права на root, хотя я и понимаю, что лучше бы я в другом каталоге работал, но я это сделаю потом, когда всё получится настроить и потом снесу систему)
Только у меня появилась новая ошибка в логе nginx: upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 62.33.49.20, server: 46.36.219.171, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/root/webserver/webserver.sock:/", host: "46.36.219.171". Не знаете как можно ее исправить?

Comment: Проблема явно в задержке, воспользуйтесь данным советом: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48858256/10090254

Comment: @floydya, я сейчас ещё посмотрел статус nginx (systemctl status nginx), там статус Active, но внизу есть 4 строки, 2 из которых кажется какие-то ошибки, мб в этом проблема? 1. nginx.service: Failed to set invocation ID on control group /system.slice/nginx.service, ignoring: Operation not permitted. 2.  Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server... 3. nginx.service: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument. 4. Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.

Comment: @floyda, с помощью совета, который вы дали, я добавил "proxy_read_timeout 300; proxy_connect_timeout 300;" в конфиг nginx и пропала одна из ошибок в "systemctl status nginx", которую я написал выше, а именно: 1. nginx.service: Failed to set invocation ID on control group /system.slice/nginx.service, ignoring: Operation not permitted. Но всё равно всё еще не работает... Такая же ошибка 502. А в var/log/nginx/error.log такая же ошибка, как в первом моём комментарии

Comment: @floyda, опять появилась эта ошибка 1. nginx.service: Failed to set invocation ID on control group /system.slice/nginx.service, ignoring: Operation not permitted. :( Я даже ничего не сделал

Comment: `nginx.service: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument.` ошибка фиксится таким образом: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nginx/+bug/1581864/comments/3 Прошу заметить, команды всего 3 - вторая и третья строка должны быть выполнены в одной.

Comment: @floydya, о боже... Заработало! Спасибо большое! Второй день вы для меня уже супер герой!) Я сначала попробовал фикс ошибки, вывожу статус, всё равно ошибка осталась, я думаю, хм, странно, перезапустил gunicorn и проверил статус - всё ок, перезапустил nginx и проверил статус - все ошибки пропали, вообще все! И я думаю, хм, падазритильна, неужели работает? Захожу и реально работает!)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста, переношу в ответ тогда все шаги решения :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*10 connect() to unix:/root/webserver/webserver.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream`

Решение: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48071739/10090254

---

`upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream`

Решение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488688/ngnix-upstream-prematurely-closed-connection-while-reading-response-header-from/48858256#48858256

---

`nginx.service: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument.`

Решение: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nginx/+bug/1581864/comments/3

Comment: Лучший человек на stackoverflow! Берите с него пример! :)